# R, pass grouped column as string to summarize function argument

Tags: r

In the code below,

```
# data frame df has columns A, B, C, D, E and few more
tmp = group_by( df, A, B, C, D)
tmp = summarise( tmp, NewColumn = min( E))
```

I would like to change column `E` in the second row to a sting or any format that will allow to have these two lines of code in a function i.e. (one possible format)

```
getSummary = function( tmp = NULL, col2pass = 'E') {

                       tmp = group_by( df, A, B, C, D)
                       tmp = summarise( tmp, NewColumn = min( col2pass))

                       return( tmp)
             }
```

I tried `tmp[ , colnames( tmp)[[ index_of_E]]]`, `tmp[ 'E']` or just `"E"` but it doesn't work apparently; in the first two cases the grouping is lost and in the second case the string is interpreted as a literal string.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You face the tricky problem of standard evaluation with `dplyr`. If you start to write functions using variable names, you might find `data.table` easier to handle (you have examples in a [post I made](https://linogaliana.netlify.app/post/datatable/datatable-nse/))

## dplyr

With `dplyr` you can use `rlang` to unquote variables:

```r
tmp = summarise( tmp, NewColumn = min(!!rlang::sym(col2pass)))
```

You can also use `{{}}` syntax to unquote ([recent feature](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/02/glue-strings-and-tidy-eval/)):

```r
tmp = summarise(tmp, NewColumn = min({{col2pass}}))
```

## data.table

You can write:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(tmp)
tmp[, .('NewColumn' = get(col2pass))]
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the very first two solutions, the first one worked, the second not. Maybe it's an update issue since it is a recent feature.

Comment: Yes it's possible. To be honest, I've never used the `{{}}` myself. I just saw a few days ago this update.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `summarise_at`

```
library(dplyr)
tmp %>%
     summarise_at(vars(col2pass), min)
```